# How to run an EXE file by clicking a button in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am doing some work with [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator), and I have to run (or) open an EXE file by clicking a pushbutton.

I am trying with this code,

```
void Widget::on_click()
{
    system("c:/.../.../NEXTA.exe");
}
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 6):

Are you searching for this: [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html).

Here is usage example from docs:

```
 QObject *parent;
 ...
 QString program = "./path/to/Qt/examples/widgets/analogclock";
 QStringList arguments;
 arguments << "-style" << "motif";

 QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
 myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```